Zeeman effect vs Stern Gerlach effect
I'm studying both effects, and I can't really understand what's the fundamental difference between them.
In both effects, we get that quantum states split due to the interaction of the atomic magnetic dipole (angular momentum + spin), and an external magnetic field, am I right?
What's the main difference?
Thanks.

Any field can provide a Zeeman effect but a non-uniform field is required for Stern Gerlach effect. To see why, using a classical analogy, look at forces on a square loop of current in a uniform and then non-uniform magnetic field.

The Zeeman effect uses the fact that atoms are magnetic dipole: The energy levels are shifted by an external magnetic field, $E = - \vec \mu \cdot \vec B$.
The main point in the Stern Gerlach experiment is that if we measure the orientation of the (atomic) magnetic dipoles in two orthogonal directions, the second measurement erases the information from the first measurement. Consider a spine $S=1/2$ particle:

The magnetic moment along any direction is allowed to take the values $\pm1/2$.
Suppose, we first measure the that the mag. dipole moment along the $x$ direction. Let's assume that the measurement yields the result $S_x=+1/2$.
Now, suppose we measure on the same particle the that the mag. dipole along the $y$ direction. Let's assume that the measurement yields the result $S_y=+1/2$.
Finally, if we use the same particle and measure the mag. dipole moment  again along the $x$ direction. The result is completely random, because the second measurement erased the "$x$-direction information". In contrast, if we don't measure the moment along the $y$ direction the information is maintained and the first and the third measurement always yield the same result.

